# cannot launch lightshot on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wine

I installed lightshot following the instructions here https://app.prntscr.com/en/wine-lightshot.html

```
sudo apt-get install wine

wget http://app.prntscr.com/build/setup-lightshot.exe

wine ./setup-lightshot.exe
```

The last line of code `wine ./setup-lightshot.exe` returns the error

```
(base) kong@kong-Standard:~$ wine ./setup-lightshot.exe
Error: Could not find process "lightshot.exe".
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
003b:err:wgl:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo  couldn't initialize OpenGL, expect problems
003b:err:graphics:USER_CheckNotLock BUG: holding USER lock
wine: Unhandled exception 0x80000003 in thread 3b at address 7BCB3EA8 (thread 003b), starting debugger...
004e:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
```

And I get the following error when I try to launch lightshot from the GUI which I do not understand

[image]

```
0x7bcb3ea8: int $3
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (34 modules)
PE    400000-  47e000   Export          lightshot
PE  7a840000-7a844000   Deferred        opengl32
PE  7b020000-7b023000   Deferred        kernelbase
PE  7b420000-7b5db000   Export          kernel32
PE  7bc30000-7bc34000   Deferred        ntdll
PE  7cb20000-7cb24000   Deferred        d3dxof
PE  7cb60000-7cb64000   Deferred        d3dcompiler_47
PE  7cbe0000-7cbe4000   Deferred        d3dx9_32
PE  7ccc0000-7ccc4000   Deferred        wined3d
PE  7ce20000-7ce24000   Deferred        d3d9
PE  7dc00000-7dc04000   Deferred        ucrtbase
PE  7ddd0000-7ddd3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1
PE  7ddf0000-7ddf3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
PE  7de00000-7de04000   Deferred        uxtheme
PE  7dea0000-7deaf000   Deferred        setupapi
PE  7e0f0000-7e0f3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
PE  7e120000-7e124000   Deferred        winex11
PE  7e3b0000-7e3b4000   Deferred        ws2_32
PE  7e3e0000-7e3eb000   Deferred        mpr
PE  7e460000-7e47f000   Deferred        wininet
PE  7e4f0000-7e4f4000   Deferred        imm32
PE  7e520000-7e523000   Deferred        usp10
PE  7e590000-7e60e000   Deferred        comctl32
PE  7e720000-7e728000   Deferred        oleaut32
PE  7e850000-7e854000   Deferred        rpcrt4
PE  7e900000-7e928000   Deferred        ole32
PE  7ea40000-7ea43000   Deferred        shcore
PE  7ea70000-7ea78000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE  7eb00000-7f3d6000   Deferred        shell32
PE  7f500000-7f504000   Deferred        advapi32
PE  7f590000-7f597000   Deferred        gdi32
PE  7f6f0000-7f7d8000   Deferred        user32
PE  7f930000-7f934000   Deferred        msvcrt
PE  7ffd0000-7ffd4000   Deferred        version
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 setup-lightshot.exe
    00000009    0
0000000e services.exe
    00000059    0
    00000053    0
    00000023    0
    0000001a    0
    00000013    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 plugplay.exe
    00000017    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
00000018 winedevice.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001c    0
    0000001b    0
    00000019    0
0000001e explorer.exe
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    0000001f    0
00000021 winedevice.exe
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
    00000022    0
0000002a setup-lightshot.tmp
    00000045    0
    0000002b    0
0000003a (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Skillbrains\lightshot\5.5.0.7\Lightshot.exe
    00000052    0
    00000040    0
    0000003b    0 <==
0000004b svchost.exe
    00000063    0
    00000062    0
    00000056    0
    00000055    0
    00000054    0
    0000004c    0
00000057 rpcss.exe
    0000005d    0
    0000005c    0
    0000005b    0
    0000005a    0
    00000058    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.11.0-27-generic
```

Comment: Check with `https://winehq.org`. Is lightshot on their list of supported applications?

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.